# how to assign a value to another class's initialize parameter from child class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

How do I assign a value to another class's initialize parameter in Ruby

```
class Ubac
  def initialize(p_str)
    @p_str=p_str
    (.....)
  end
  def method1
    (.....)
  end

end

class ReqQuote < Ubac
  def initialize(p_code)
     @code=p_code
     # here how do i initialize the @p_str to the value which is returned from the get_data method below.?
  end
  def get_data(symbol)
     (....) # fetch data
     data 
  end
  def methodx
    (.....)
  end


end
```

Here how do I initialize `@p_str` with the value which is returned from the `get_data` method as if `p_str` was initialized from the `Ubac` class's `initialize`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case you can just put `@p_str=` in `Ubac#initialize`. However, you can call `Ubac`'s `initialize` from `ReqQuote` using `super` e.g.

```
class ReqQuote < Ubac
  def initialize(p_code)
     super(get_data(some_symbol))
     @code=p_code
  end
  ...
```

This is generally a good practice because it means any other initialisation code added to `Ubac` will also get executed when you create a `ReqQuote`.

Comment: Watch out calling get_data before the constructor is complete, this could lead to unexpected bugs. Especially if get_data calls other instance methods, or if get_data is overridden in a child class.

Answer (score 0):

You write `@p_str = get_data(some_symbol)`.